# hg serve bound to 8000 successfully, but can't be access and pinged

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgserve

I got this problem when I use `hg serve`, and it said, 
`listening at http://localhost6.localdomain6:8000/ (bound to *:8000)`

I assumed that the server already running.

But when I want to access the server via web browser, it said,
"Unable to Connect"

And I can't ping the url, too.

I use Mercurial in Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit. (the newest mercurial)

This is what my `iptables -L` shows:

```
kiddo@kiddo-K42Jr:~$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for kiddo: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootps 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:bootps 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Well, you cannot ping a URL _anyway_, only a host. Have you tried `hg serve -a 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Is there a firewall in the way (`iptables -L`)?

Comment: this i smy iptables -L shows:

Comment: Kiddo: did you solve this problem? If my suggestion helped you, then please mark it as accepted so that the question is no longer "unanswered".

Answer (score 0):

The address http://localhost6.localdomain6:8000/ is for IPv6, but `hg serve` will only use IPv4 by default. This makes it sound like your Ubuntu has a wrongly configured local host name.

In any case: go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in your browser instead.